# How to get to linear form?

Tags: calculus

This question is probably dead easy, but I am having difficulties to answer it.
I found the function of the tangent to the curve at a point of abscissa a by doing this :
$$f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)$$
So if I want to "convert" this expression to :
$$ax+b$$
In this expression, what is a, and what is b ?

EDIT : I think that $a$ is $f'(a)$ but I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tangent to the curve at a point of $x_0$:
$$   f(x) = f'({x_0})(x - {x_0}) + f({x_0})  = f'({x_0})x + f({x_0}) - {x_0}f'({x_0})  $$
So :

$$\eqalign{
  & a = f'(a)  \cr 
  & b = f(a) - af'(a) \cr} $$

Note: There are two different $a$ in $a=f'(a) ~!$

In order to avoid confusion, I rewrite it at $(x_0,f(x_0))$:
$$\eqalign{
  & a = f'({x_0})  \cr 
  & b = f({x_0}) - x_0f'({x_0}) \cr} $$

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is the coefficient in from of $x$ in the expression of $y = f(x) = ax+b$

$b$ is the value of $f(0) $ in the expression of $y = f(x) = ax+b$